# Run docker compose file without internet connection

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have a .NET project with docker support, so I run docker-compose.yml with docker-compose.override.yml file - Windows OS with Linux docker containers.

My idea is to download all necessary images and then run that same docker-compose file without internet connection. So, i will have connection initially, download all the images, and then go offline and run the app.

Any idea how can I do that?

Comment: Download all necessary images using `docker pull imagename` and then run

Comment: You've accurately described the solution. Please update the question with the steps you took to attempt solving the problem and error messages you encountered.

Answer (score 2):

That should be no problem at all, if the images all exist locally docker-compose will just use them when you start.

As long as the images them selves doesn't require Internet of course.

Comment: yes but every time there is a check if images are up to date on hub, and for that docker requires connection...

Comment: Could you please describe the means of getting images to the local cache else the answer is incomplete?

Comment: @zlaaya There is no check if images are up-to-date only available locally or not. In fact we had to write a wrapper tool to always fetch an up-to-date image if available

Comment: i get an error in VS "An error occurred while sending thew request", so i assumed it is because docker tried to get latest version from hub. maybe making compose file independent from VS, and run from command line will do the job?

Comment: docker-compose will not check anything online. If the image is present locally it will be used. You can do `docker-compose pull` to force a re-download of images. I cannot attest to how VS does thing but try it command line just in case.

Comment: you were right, no need to download images, when they are in cache, they work without problems, except those which require connection. i solved my problem with making .yaml file independent from Visual Studio. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do below steps

- First over the internet get to build all required docker images.
- Then save/export those images in the tar file by using below command

  `docker save image_name > /image/mynewimage.tar`
- The go offline, copy those tar file on another or same machine and load those images by using below command

  `docker load < /image/mynewimage.tar`
- Then run normal docker run commands, you already have got all images locally hence docker will not try to get it download from the internet.

This should work, let me know if you need any help with this.

Please post your docker-compose file, if in case of any issue with above approach.

Comment: [just an idea] I am looking for some portable docker repository, where you can push the image and then plug that computer with intranet and run docker compose file to get the images